# Redirect for UpdateView

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

I have the following view in Django:

```
class LoanEditView(UpdateView):
    model = Loans
    form_class = LoanForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('edit', kwargs={
            'pk': self.object.pk,
        })
```

I have a url path that works to call the update view:

```
path('edit/<int:pk>', LoanEditView.as_view(), name='edit')
```

But now my home page view is broken - I can't seem to redirect from the edit view?

On top of this, I would really like to pass the pk from a link in my html along the lines of:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit' %}" class="btn btn-primary" pk=loan.pk>Edit</a>
```

With profound apologies to anyone following my questions today - I've been at this for ten hours and starting to make silly mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

You specified `pk` as an argument of the `<a ... pk="loan.pk">` tag, not as a named parameter of the `{% url ... %}` template tag. Using `pk=loan.pk` does not make any sense anyway, since it is not a template variable (between `{{ ... }}`), or in a template tag (between `{% ... %}`), hence that would mean that your HTML literally contains `pk="loan.pk"`, so not the primary key of the `loan`, but just a string `"loan.pk"`.

You need to specify the primary key `pk` *in* the `{% url ... %} template tag, like:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit' pk=loan.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit</a>
```